# Add dynamically a row after gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am retrieving different types of a product and their price values to gridview
as

```
 -----------------------------------------
   | Product   |  pen  |  pencil  |   crayon |
   | ----------|-------|----------|--------- |
   | Price     |  4    |  2       |   6      |
    -----------------------------------------
```

I want to add Total price row below to the grid view , depending upon the number of quantity from the drop downlist.

The total price row has to be visible after selecting value from the drop down list

Comment: Could you give more context, and better explain what you are trying to achieve? I just couldn't understand.

Comment: i have edited, let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Better, but what is the language and environment?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing your code would be helpful for us.
Anyways here are some links that might be helpful to your cause

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479339.aspx

and

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/aspnet-gridview-examples-and-samples-in.html

Comment: Your answer would be stronger if you explained why those links are relevant to this question.